# Paperclip attachments don't save under unicorn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, unicorn

I'm running a rails 3.0.12 application with Paperclip 2.6 under Ubuntu + Nginx + Unicorn setup. In production, my image attachments seemed to upload fine, but upon checking the image path, I couldn't find the files, so I started messing around.

Ultimately, I found that if I ran the built-in rails dev server (rails s), the attachments would upload just fine to the correct path. But under unicorn, while the attachments do get uploaded, a) they get saved to /tmp/**randompath** on the server, and all the resized images for each of the styles also get saved with a bunch of random characters in the filename, including the upload date and time.

Not sure what is going on here. Here is the rails log when run under the rails dev server (in the production environment):

```
Command :: identify -format %wx%h '/tmp/stream20120626-4215-axmd16.png[0]'
Command :: convert '/tmp/stream20120626-4215-axmd16.png[0]' -resize "x100" -crop "100x100+185+0" +repage '/tmp/stream20120626-4215-axmd1620120626-4215-1droo3w'
Command :: identify -format %wx%h '/tmp/stream20120626-4215-axmd16.png[0]'
Command :: convert '/tmp/stream20120626-4215-axmd16.png[0]' -resize "280x" -crop "280x55+0+2" +repage '/tmp/stream20120626-4215-axmd1620120626-4215-fzxeg1'
...
...
UPDATE `organizations` SET `logo_file_name` = 'logo.png', `logo_file_size` = 5682,             `logo_updated_at` = '2012-06-26 19:48:47', `updated_at` = '2012-06-26 19:48:48' WHERE `organizations`.`id` = 1
[paperclip] Saving attachments.
[paperclip] saving /home/deploy/apps/xxx_staging/releases/20120626193037/public/system/organization/1/original/logo.png
[paperclip] saving /home/deploy/apps/xxx_staging/releases/20120626193037/public/system/organization/1/thumb/logo.png
```

And under unicorn, the log shows:

```
Command :: identify -format %wx%h '/tmp/1docway_logo20120626-11230-1wodane.jpg[0]'
Command :: convert '/tmp/1docway_logo20120626-11230-1wodane.jpg[0]' -resize "x100" -crop "100x100+135+0" +repage '/tmp/1docway_logo20120626-11230-1wodane20120626-11230-1y0j5hm'
Command :: identify -format %wx%h '/tmp/1docway_logo20120626-11230-1wodane.jpg[0]'
Command :: convert '/tmp/1docway_logo20120626-11230-1wodane.jpg[0]' -resize "280x" -crop "280x55+0+10" +repage '/tmp/1docway_logo20120626-11230-1wodane20120626-11230-1bwx4go'
[paperclip] Saving attachments.
[paperclip] deleting /home/deploy/apps/xxx_staging/releases/20120620214744/public/organization/1/original/1docway_logo.png
[paperclip] deleting /home/deploy/apps/xxxx_staging/releases/20120620214744/public/organization/1/thumb/1docway_logo.png
```

As you can see, the second set of logs has no UPDATE command being run, or files being saved to the /home/deploy/apps/xxx_staging/releases/xxx/public/system/ folder